# How to add a parent category in wordpress using WP eCommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using [wp e-Commerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) to make an `eCommerce site`. There `after install` I have `added products` under `Products >> Add new products`. All this working is fine. But I want to show all this `products under their parent category`. Means under `electronics category` all the `electronics products` will be there. So how to `add a parent category`there? Any help will be most appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a electronic category under Products->categories after that create a child category like ironbox,remote etc. Under Add New Product Category you can find parent select the parent category as electronic. Then create a new page you can find the icon for insert product insert the parent category to show.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating all the parent categories you can think of.  Then, when you're creating child categories, you'll notice the 3rd option down on the left of the body (below slug) is a "Parent" drop down.

To answer you question:  In my experience, if a product is assigned a category, that product will display when viewing the parent category of the one that is immediately associated.  As long as your categories are set up with a proper parent/child relationship, it should work like this by default.